# Source that it is a mitzvah to let your seat be used

Tags: sources-mekorot, synagogue, hachnasat-orchim-guests, makom-kavuah

I've heard many times that to let others use your seat in shul is a fulfillment of the mitzvah of accepting guests.

Is there a respectable (by most Jews) written source for this? Where?

Comment: What I found today, http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/8779 , http://www.shulpolitics.com/2011/11/15/pardon-me-but-youre-in-my-seat/

Comment: Practically speaking it makes little difference - having guests is itself a sub-category of chesed (see Shabbat 127b with Rashi), which giving up your seat certainly is. So it's a fulfillment of the same general mitzvah as having guests even if he's not technically classified as a guest.

Comment: The large shul in Boca Raton, FL actually makes it one of their rules for maintaining membership! In their membership guidelines, they specifically state that chessed is a foundation and requirement of every shul member. One is allowed to have a *makom kavu'ah* (fixed seat), but if one wants it, he must arrive on time to use it. One is forbidden to kick someone out of his seat, and a member who does this is chastised and may actually lose his membership privileges! I'm impressed!!